# Ant & JUnit & Jacoco Coverage Error

Tags: java, junit, ant, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to use 'Jacoco' in 'Ant' build with 'Junit'. However, I used simple code for testing, Jacoco did not cover any thing. Build run well, execute run well, Junit also show me the results, however, Jacoco can't.

```
<target name="cov-test" depends ="build">
    <jacoco:coverage>
        <junit showoutput="true" printsummary="on" enabletestlistenerevents="true" fork="true">
            <classpath path="classes" />
            <classpath path="lib/junit.jar" />
            <classpath path="lib/hamcrest-core.jar" />

            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />

            <test name="SimpleTest">
            </test>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>

    <jacoco:coverage>
        <java classname="SimpleTest" fork="true">
            <classpath path="classes" />
            <classpath path="lib/junit.jar" />
            <classpath path="lib/hamcrest-core.jar" />
        </java>
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>

<target name="cov-report" depends="cov-test">
    <jacoco:report>
        <executiondata>
            <fileset file="jacoco.exec" />
        </executiondata>

        <structure name="SimpleTest">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="classes" />
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles>
                <fileset dir="src" />
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>

        <html destdir="report" />
    </jacoco:report>

</target>
```

This is my build.xml of ant, Jacoco show me the report, however, it never cover any class files. Evenly, the main class does not execute. My simple java test code is

```
public class Simple 
{
public Simple() {
}

public int exec(int i) {
    if (i > 0)
        return i ;
    return i * -1 ;
}
}

   public class SimpleTest
   {
    @Test
    public void testSimple1() {
    Simple s = new Simple() ;
    assertTrue(s.exec(-1) == 1) ;
}

    @Test
    public void testSimple2() {
    Simple s = new Simple() ;
    assertTrue(s.exec(1) == 1) ;
}

   public static void main(String [] args) {
    SimpleTest s = new SimpleTest() ;

    //s.testSimple1() ;
    //s.testSimple2() ;
}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did I solve this problem.
However, the problem was the directory's location.
In the way of directory location, there should not be any other language.
For example, I run this xml on

C://

Then it runs well,
However

C://한국어//Test

Then it does not run well.